# Projetos criados no Visual Studio 2015 são reconhecidos no Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Pois projetos que são criados no 2013 não são reconhecidos no 2012, pois tenho que criar tudo na mão, pois o visual não reconhece o mesmo como um projeto MVC.

Comment: Vou fazer um teste aqui. Ainda não instalei o Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

É para funcionar, não achei ninguém reclamando. Achei pessoas dizendo que projetos do 2013 são reconhecidos pelo 2012, ao contrário do que você diz. Então pode ser que você esteja tendo problemas específicos. Até onde eu sei havia problemas em versões anteriores.

Claro que versões novas **podem** usar recursos novos que não serão reconhecidos por versões do VS mais antigas. Aí seria incompatível mesmo. Em todas versões acontecem este tipo de coisa. Por isso o arquivo `.sln` possui a versão do formato.

Se você precisa disto deve ter ambos, então é fácil testar e descobrir se o seu caso dá certo ou não. Aí se for algum problema específico, pode perguntar aqui (abrindo algo com todos os detalhes) se tem como contornar.

O projeto tipo MVC no VS 2015 tem melhorias, evidentemente que se algo novo for usado, o VS 2013 não irá reconhecer mesmo.

Eu sei que não responde ao que você quer saber mas seria bom ler [isso](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/porting-migrating-and-upgrading-visual-studio-projects?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Answer (score 1):

## Projetos criados no Visual Studio 2015 são reconhecidos no Visual Studio 2013?

Até a data desta resposta, sim. Fiz um teste criando um projeto do tipo ASP.NET Web Application.

Aliás, o projeto do Visual Studio 2015 já vem com todos os pacotes na versão mais atual, ao contrário do Visual Studio 2013 que, ao iniciar um projeto, é preciso atualizar os pacotes através de um `Update-Package`.

Ainda sobre o Visual Studio 2015, não existe mais a possibilidade de criação de projeto com compatibilidade retroativa para o Visual Studio 2012, como havia no Visual Studio 2013.