# Versionar projeto com Visual Studio 2013 e 2015

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, versionamento, visual-studio-2015

Um projeto que utiliza duas versões do `Visual Studio (2013 e 2015)` pode acontecer conflitos, por exemplo, com arquivo `.csproj` ou outro qualquer?

Obs: Não quero ignorar este arquivo no versionamento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há uma [pergunta sobre diferenças nos arquivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77225/101). Os arquivos os 2015 podem conter informações de coisas não reconhecidas no 2013. Então se você usar coisas específicas do que só pode ser usado no projeto do 2015, ele conterá coisas que não poderão estar no arquivo do 2013.

É comum um usuário do 2015 que faça uso destes recursos *commitar* o arquivo sem muita preocupação do que foi adicionado. Ele faz o *merge* normal e eventualmente pode ter fazer manualmente. Aí um usuário pega esta versão e põe no 2013 e tenta usar. Pronto, você tem um arquivo com informações inválidas.

Não sei dizer todas as consequências disto, mas é um problema. Pode ser que o VS 2013 retire estas informações, aí quando *commitar*, vai sem uma informação que era necessária no 2015. O usuário do 2015 pega e precisa arrumar o arquivo, e sempre vai ficar nisto.

Note que pode ser que estas informações extras não sejam necessárias em certos cenários, aí pode funcionar ok. Então depende do cenário.

Comment: Esta resposta não é uma maravilha mas a outra estava confusa.

Answer (score 1):

Depende. Se o projeto foi criado no VS 2013, não vão ocorrer problemas para abrir e editar no VS 2015 e manter o versionamento. A compatibilidade com o Framework 4.5 é completa. Porém, caso o projeto tenha sido criado no VS 2015 .NET Framework 4.6, vão existir problemas de compatibilidade.

Comment: Isto não responde a pergunta. Isto já foi respondido http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77225/101 Ele está perguntando outra coisa. Eu só não respondo porque não sei exatamente todas consequências e soluções, mas é óbvio que haverá conflitos.

Comment: Talvez eu tenha me expressado mal. Não vão ocorrer conflitos utilizando as duas versões (eu falei problemas). Trabalhamos por um tempo aqui na empresa com duas versões do VS e versionamento (utilizando o tortoise SVN) e não tivemos problema algum, exceto os conflitos normais que podem ocorrer com o arquivo csproj quando dois usuários adicionam arquivos e o merge não consegue resolver sozinho.

Comment: Você fala que não terão conflitos, exceto os conflitos normais. Então terão conflitos.

Comment: Conflitos normais eu me referi aos conflitos que ocorrem mesmo trabalhando com a mesma versão do VS. Não há nada novo. Criar um projeto no 2015 pode gerar conflitos a mais quando versionar e trabalhar com o 2013, mas um projeto do 2013 não gerou nenhum problema ao versionar e trabalhar com o 2015. Falo da experiência prática que tive.